# TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: angular

```
<mat-carousel timings="200ms ease-in" [autoplay]="true" interval="3000">
  <mat-carousel-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let i = index" [image]="slide.image" 
            overlayColor="#ffffff" [hideOverlay]="false">
</mat-carousel-slide>
```

`interval="3000"` is throwing error 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `[interval]="3000"`.

Without the `[..]` you are not using Angular typed binding but just "regular" string-only binding. Or said differently, `interval="3000"` is the same as `[interval]="'3000'"`.